# How to know if something is programmed in Flash or Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I was looking for examples of Javascript games and I came across [this](http://digitalinsane.com/games/pacman/). It looks like Flash. I tried looking at the source code, and all I see are a bunch of div tags, but not really any Javascript. I couldn't find the code that actually runs the game.

Is this Flash or Javascript? How can you tell?

Comment: If there an `<embed>` or `<object>` tag present in the HTML source? Is there a JavaScript in `<script>` *or* a link to external HTML in the source? (One of those is true and one is false in this case: right-click and choose "View Page Source".)

Answer (score 3):

It's Javascript.

When you right click it gives you the native browser context menu. Right-clicking anything in Flash will give you a Flash context menu.  The only time that method fails is when you get no context menu at all.

Also, highlight the text "Press enter".  It uses native text highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know is impossible to hide the typical secondary flash context menu telling the version, etc...

I found is using a core.js javascript

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable the plugin of `shockwave flash` from browser's options. Then refresh page and see, whether 'target flash' disappears. If so then it was flash.